# How to install .jar dependencies on another computer?

Tags: java, maven

I have a project that I built using Netbeans and maven that requires some external packages, so they are listed in the dependencies section of pom.xml. When I build the jar it downloads all the dependencies and it runs fine on my computer. If I transfer the jar to another computer and run it though, it crashes when it comes to a class that it can't find (in this case org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils). I figured out how to package all of the dependencies in the jar file, but the the file is 100MB instead of 40KB. What is the general process here when distributing a java program? Do I just include all the dependencies and distribute the large file, or is there a way to automatically download the needed dependencies on the new computer? One reason I would prefer a smaller file is that it has to run on a server, so for testing I can push a new version to the server much quicker if the file size is smaller and it can just find the dependencies elsewhere on the system.

Comment: can use Maven with `pom.xml`. Just checkout the source code only on the new computer. Then standing in the directory having `pom.xml` file, run the command `mvn clean package`, Maven will download all the required jars for you. Make sure that the SDK and Maven are set up properly on the new machine.

Comment: On a side note — is your server’s network connection slow enough that there’s a big enough difference in upload speed to matter? I understand the question, just mildly curious based on the reasoning you provided.

Comment: What kind of application did you develop?

Comment: The upload speed at my house is only about 5 Mbps, so uploading 100 MB takes a while

Answer (score 1):

You can make use the appassembler plugin to create a zip or tar file that has your application and all of its dependencies, and a command-line shell script to invoke Java with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question had two questions. So to answer the first question, as you suggested you could bundle your dependencies in a jar and use the jar to extract your dependencies and use the java code. In order to combat the large dependency jars, you could use [ProGuard](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava). It's a cool tool and allows you to shrink dependency jars, usually used for android (Try using their obfuscator too).

"Is there a way to automatically download the needed dependencies on the new computer?"

Yes, using the terminal (or cmd prompt) go to your folder where your pom file is located and type:

```
    mvn clean compile
```

This will download all your dependencies into the .m2 folder. You could then use maven on the other computer to run the program or pass the folder as an argument to java. However, refixing the folder structure might be a pain. To use maven:

```
   mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="<your class path>" -Dexec.args="<Args here>"
```

You don't need to specify where your dependencies are since Maven handles that for you in the pom.xml file.